# Conversion of JSON String to add parent

Tags: javascript, json

How can I change this

```
return {
businessSummary: d[0].GeneralInformation.BusinessSummary,
businessUrl: d[0].GeneralInformation.WebSites.HomePage
};
```

to show output which is like this. Just want to add a parent data node on top

[image: desired JSON oputput]

At the moment its like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an object with the properties **businessSummary** and **businessUrl** at the moment. What you want to do is to return an object with the property **data** which contains the object with your other properties. Like this:

```
return { data: {
    businessSummary: d[0].GeneralInformation.BusinessSummary,
    businessUrl: d[0].GeneralInformation.WebSites.HomePage
}};
```